# How can you create a .xml file and set its contents to equal the contents of an NSString

Tags: iphone, xml, email

I am attempting to create a .xml file and set the contents of the file to equal a predetermined string.

I have built the XML and am currently storing it in an NSString.

I want to put the contents of this string into a file with the extension of .xml and send an email with the file as an attachment.

I am able to email PDFs and assumed creating the file with an extension of .xml would be the easy bit, but alas I cannot do it.

If anyone could offer a helping hand I would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 NSString *path = ...;
 NSString *string = ...;
 NSError *error;

 BOOL ok = [string writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
 if (!ok) {

 // an error occurred
 NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",path, [error localizedFailureReason]);

 // implementation continues ..
```

[Writing to Files and URLs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html)

Comment: Many thanks. This was the line i was looking for - [string writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];